# Which URLs should be checked regularly to maintain the site?

Tags: discussion

I've posted a Community Wiki answer below with URLs that you can check to maintain content on the site.

Feel free to edit it with any more useful links we can check regularly.

Answer (score 4):

Insofar as possible, please fix everything in a post at once; and limit the number of edits you perform in one go, to avoid [flooding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122567/allow-non-bumping-minor-edits-but-review-them-on-review) the homepage.

---

**SEDE** (updated Monday 3am UTC):

- [Questions without a question in the title](http://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/503133/find-questions-titles-that-are-not-phrased-as-questions) <sup>120</sup>
- [Questions containing "hi/thanks"](http://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/508074/questions-with-signatures-hi-thanks) <sup>1</sup>
- [Tags without a tag wiki excerpt](https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/309531/tags-without-a-tag-wiki-excerpt) <sup>10</sup>
- [Tags without a tag wiki body](https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/309530/tags-without-a-tag-wiki-body) <sup>242</sup>
- [Posts with plain-text links](https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/309558/find-unlinked-links) <sup>516</sup>
- [Posts containing a single \$ sign (broken MathJax)](https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/309694/find-posts-with-broken-mathjax-single-dollar-sign) <sup>182</sup>
- [Short answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/309546/short-answers) <sup>301</sup>

**Av.SE** (5 minute delay):

- [Questions without any tags](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) <sup>0</sup>
- [Questions with no upvoted answers](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/unanswered) <sup>120</sup>

Comment: I would note that the two tag wiki ones are really good candidates for fixing: Creating a Tag Wiki Excerpt (that shows up when tags autocomplete) can help keep people from flailing about over-tagging things, and a good solid tag wiki can be an excellent educational resource (one that's even worth referencing in answers sometimes).